# Is it possible to draw charts from csv file in c3.js?

Tags: c3.js

this is my code and csv file.
The c3js chart is not displaying properly when I have a date field in a CSV file. I have set the x axis as type timeseries. There are only two columns in CSV file. "Data" and "count",

```js
html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="c3.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script src="d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="c3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        url: 'dates.csv'
    }
});




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
data,count
120,80
140,50
170,100
150,70
180,120
```

Comment: it does appear it's possible http://c3js.org/samples/data_load.html in fact it seems like the norm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521945/c3-js-exclude-columns-from-csv

Comment: i did not understand ur answer..can u share some example or correct it?       but i already attached script file(c3.min.js,d3.min.js) and c3.css files in that folder

Comment: Ya its working now...thank you so much..@Elder Smash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="c3.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script src="d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="c3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        x: 'Date', 
        x_Format: '%Y-%m-%d', 
        url: 'dates.csv', 
    },
    axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'timeseries', 
    }
}
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this code is working now..