# C3 : selecting csv column input

Tags: c3.js

How do I select which columns will be graphed in C3.js from a csv data file containing 1200 rows and thirteen columns.
Addendum: I've edited the file and made changes. The file works. All issues resolved. For general information, I retrieved the basic document from a copy of the JSFiddle page. Apparently, each JSFiddle page source code contains links to two (offline) functional copies of the code on the JSFiddle. The code as written in the JSFiddle page did not work offline.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/c3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./resources/c3.css">
<style type="text/css"></style>
<title>once again</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
d3.csv("./data/dataXY_11-21-2016.csv")
    .row(function(d) { return [d.time12, d.PVpower, d.Elevation]; })
    .get(function(error,rows) { 
        rows.unshift (["time 12", "PV array power(W)", "Elevation"])
        console.log(rows); 
      var chart = c3.generate({
        size:{
        width: 1000,
        height: 400
        },
    bindto: '#chart',
          data: {
              rows: rows,
              type: 'line',
                x: 'time 12',
                xFormat:'%I:%M:%S %p'
          },
            point: {show: false},
            tooltip: {show: false},
        axis: {
            x: {
                localtime: true,
                type:'timeseries',
                tick:{
                    //culling:{max: 50},
                    fit: true,
                    count: 50,
                    format: '%I:%M:%S %p',
                    rotate: 65,         
                      }//end tick
                },//end x

            y: {
                max: 350,
                min: 0
                } //end y
            },//end axis

        grid:{
            x:{
                show: true
            },//end x
            y:{
                show: true
              }//end y
            }//end grid
      });
});
}//]]> 
</script>
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
<script>
  if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
    window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
      height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
      slug: "None"
    }], "*")
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at this question here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521945/c3-js-exclude-columns-from-csv . Basically you have to filter the csv outside of generating the c3 chart first. Then use that filtered data in the c3 chart generate function.

Comment: As you can see from the script, I employed solution #2, and that does not work as is.

Comment: But you're trying to do the csv filtering within the c3 generate function. It needs to be done outside of that.

Comment: I've modified the script for other changes as seen above. I also inserted the filter in its own script, both, before and after the generate script. No go. I inserted the filter in the same script as the generate function, both, before and after the generate function. No go.

Comment: Oh, the 'columns' function had no effect either.

Comment: I have, since, discovered that d3.csv is a separate file in the d3 distribution. Also found csv filtering is not inherently supported in d3, but that json is. Looking at csv-to-json on-the-fly conversion.

Comment: I could use the show/hide features but the entire file is still loaded. I can use the json filtering function but csv files are relatively compact and I'm going to be dealing with hundreds of files of fifteen variables/columns and 1200 rows on a Raspberry Pi with a 16gb SD card as long term storage device..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example I've messed about with on jsfiddle (code below)

http://jsfiddle.net/Lpatkpj1/

I load the csv, the `.row` function then filters each row into a new format (array as opposed to object), cherry-picking just two columns on the way, which is then all returned in `.get`(csv example is just one that was handy on the web). Then I add the names of the data to the front of the rows array using unshift. A very minimal c3.generate can then show this information using the `rows:` option, anything else you want can be added on.

```
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/master/usedcars.csv")
    .row(function(d) { return [d.price, d.mileage]; })
    .get(function(error, rows) { 
        rows.unshift (["Price", "Mileage"])

        var chart = c3.generate({
          data: {
              rows: rows,
              type: 'line'
          },
        });
});
```

*"I have, since, discovered that d3.csv is a separate file in the d3 distribution"* - it can be, but you can get d3.js all bundled up including the csv functionality. Bear in mind c3 does not currently work with v4 of d3, only v3 - https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1648.

Comment: I got around to working with the script. These are my results:

d3.v3 :no errors, no columns array
d3.v4 :errors with c3 category but adds columns


    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'category10' of c3.js.5783
    
    at stacktest.html:15
    at Object.<anonymous> (d3.v4.min.js:7)
    at d.call (d3.v4.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.e (d3.v4.min.js:6)

Comment: When I place the script, as written in JSFiddle, into an HTML file, add the doctype, script t and sources, should the data be graphed? Is there something in JSFiddle not shown? If you haven't figured it out yet, I'm relatively new to d3 and c3 and haven't worked heavily in javascript for a few years.

Comment: d3.v4 won't work with c3 full stop so you need d3.v3. The example fiddle posted above will work with the 'rows' option in the c3.generate syntax rather than 'columns'. To get it to work with your data you just need to change the headings that are included.

Comment: I've got the document working. The code is completely functional.